# Intellij Idea & WebStorm NPM versions latest and more

Tags: node.js, intellij-idea, npm, updates

I encounter too many times when my Node Packages are not up to date and I want to keep them updated and not waste too much time on it.

So, I wanted to check all options using my favorite JetBrains IDEs & other tools to track those packages and keep the latest version when needed.

Comment: Note that self-answered questions still need to be high quality, on-topic questions.

Comment: can you give more details on that comment? I will be happy for suggestions on how to make it better.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a list of options to track it:

1. I found out about simple and useful package [npm-check-updates](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check-updates) which really doing the work of listing all packages you have in the project and show the ones, not in the latest version. You need to install it globally to be available for all projects, `npm install -g npm-check-updates`.

   - to see list use `ncu` in project folder
   - to update all list use `ncu -u` or `ncu -a`, instruction in the console after running `ncu`.
   - `npm install` to install all. I also remove the folder `node_modules` and then do `npm install` to see all installed correctly.
2. Inside Intellij Idea & WebStorm you can go to `package.json` and hover+Cmd key (windows Ctrl key) the package name and a nice tooltip with the latest version will pop up, for example:

   [image]
3. Inside Intellij Idea & WebStorm go to `Preferences` menu item and navigate to `Node.js and NPM`. you can see the full packages list and if it in the latest version on it right.

   [image]